# Web Scrapy!! How can I crawl using Click event data?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, scrapy

I try to crawl this page : http://www.11st.co.kr/html/main.html
but there are some problems.
First, Scrapy cannot interpret javascript.
I want to get some 'href' data to crawl again in that button(red square one)

Site screencapture

[image]

even I cannot use selenium.
Because button code is in script.
so xpath can't find.

```
<script id="headerNavigationTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#ifCond templateType '===' 'main'}}
    <nav class="header_gnb" id="gnbNavArea">
    {{else}}
    <div class="header_gnb" id="gnbNavArea">
    {{/ifCond}}
        <div class="inner">
            <h1 class="hide">대메뉴</h1>
            <div class="gnb_l">
                <div class="gnb_nav gnb_nav_category" id="gnbCategoryArea">
                    <p name="gnbNavBtn"><button type="button" class="gnb_btn_all" data-ga-event-category="PC_GNB" data-ga-event-action="전체보기 버튼" data-ga-event-label=""><span class="in_btn"><span class="ico"></span>전체보기</span></button></p>
                    <div class="gnb_nav_category_layer">
                        <div class="gnb_total_category">
                            <div class="row" id="navCtgrRow1"></div>
                            <div class="row" id="navCtgrRow2"></div>
                            <div class="row" id="navCtgrRow3"></div>
                            <div class="row" id="navCtgrRow4"></div>
                            <div class="row" id="navCtgrRow5"></div>
                            <div class="row" id="navCtgrRow6"></div>
                            <div class="row" id="navCtgrRow7"></div>
                            <div class="row" id="navCtgrRow8"></div>
                            <div class="row" id="navCtgrRow9"></div>
```

I want to get data that hide in

```
//div[@class = "gnb_total_category"]/div
```

how can I crawl.
Please help me.

Comment: Check the source code for json data. If there is json data in the source code of that page, you can use xpath to extract that and do your thing. Otherwise you'll have to check for other loaded files (in chrome, inspect - network tab might be helpful). Just try to pinpoint where the data you need is coming from.

Comment: @김혜지, show the exact output you want to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following script to get required data:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.11st.co.kr/html/main.html')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), '전체보기')]").click()
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="gnb_total_category"]/div').text)
```

Comment: thank you! i had mistake. Thanks for your mention, Now I solved